# Windows 8.1: Ad-hoc wifi network manager

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, wifi-configuration, ad-hoc-network

Connecting to ad-hoc wifi networks has become fairly inconvenient in Windows 8.1. It requires executing several shell commands and copy/paste of strings... (See [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-networking/windows-81-ad-hoc-not-showing/5d75d887-ff59-425e-a480-9f80ada63627).)

Does anybody know a nice tool that shows existing ad-hoc networks and allows me to join them with a simple click? - Like it used to be possible in previous Windows versions...